# PHP session lost in the same page?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm trying to create a simple search page in PHP.

the page has some $SESSION variables that has been passed through from the Previous page.

when I reach the page (BEFORE searching), the page looks like this: `my-page.php`

and I have this session variable passed on from the previous page to my-page.php:

```
         $_SESSION["phone"] = $Cphone ;


         $CUphone = $_SESSION["phone"];

         echo $CUphone;
```

up to this point everything works fine and I get the echo-ed `$CUphone` on my-page.php properly.

now, there is a simple search form on my-page.php so I can search mysql database if I wanted to.

**like so:**

```
<form action="my-page.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
</form>
```

and when I search using the form above, I get the results properly too as expected... and the page will become

`my-page.php?search=SOMETHING`

and the search function works perfectly fine too....

BUT the problem will start from here (the moment I search for something)...

I basically loose `echo $CUphone;` if the `my-page.php` becomes `my-page.php?search=SOMETHING`..

which means I loose the sessions because `$CUphone` is stored in sessions like i said above.

so is there any way to keep the sessions on `my-page.php?search=something` ?

any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you run $_SESSION["phone"] = $Cphone ; on every page request? That might explain why it goes missing, if $Cphone is ever not set.

Comment: @Erik, every page?! its all on the same page mate. my-page.php..

Comment: Well u should add the code that defines the `$Cphone` var

Comment: Where does $Cphone come from? If you change the $_SESSION contents on every request, then you are not really recovering anything from the session.

Comment: @william But, with every `GET` request the page reloads. If during the page reload the original `$Cphone` is empty your session will be empty.

Comment: @DarkBee, i have! its in my first part of question!

Comment: The first part is you setting a session var with, for us a unknown,  `$Cphone`

Comment: No william..you are setting the value of `$CUphone`. DarkBee asked for `$Cphone`. where the value of this variable is set?

Comment: @Erik, it comes from two previous pages. and on my-page.php I get it properly but when I search and my-page.php becomes my-page.php?search=something I loose it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a condition when setting the session variable.

```
session_start();

if($Cphone) {
    $_SESSION["phone"] = $Cphone;
} else {
    echo "phone number does not exist";
}

if($_SESSION["phone"]) {
    $CUphone = $_SESSION["phone"];
} else {
    echo "session does not exist";
}
```

It's best to set your session variables only one time unless there is a good reason to change them. This is a very basic recommendation not knowing anything about your application. But it's best to make your condition as specific as possible.

Comment: not sure what the condition would do to be honest. I still loose the session when the page becomes `my-page.php?search=something`

Comment: It depends on how `$Cphone` is being populated. Seems whatever code is creating that is changing the variable. Would be best to create your session along with that and only execute it once.

Comment: try using ... `if(isset($Cphone) && $Cphone ){}`

Comment: @william only way the session could be empty is if you are resetting/unsetting the `$Cphone` variable on `my-page.php` or your are not calling `session_start()`. This also assumes that you are not doing any redirection. If there is redirection you will also need a `session_start()` on that page as well.

Comment: I have all the mentioned points checked. I have session_start() on my page, I am not redirecting, its all in the same page (my-page.php), I am not resetting the $Cphone either.. and still loosing the session! its killing me :(

Comment: So `$_SESSION["phone"] = $Cphone;` is on previous page, and `$CUphone = $_SESSION["phone"];` is on `my-page.php`?

Comment: Yes, it was... now I moved the form to A page before my-page.php to make it shorter and closer to my-page.php and I use     $Cphone = $_POST["phone"]; above my session codes and I get the value properly on my-page.php when I echo $CUphone on my page but AGAIN I loose it when my-page.php becomes my-page.php?search=something!

Comment: Try `var_dump($_SESSION["phone"]); exit;`

Comment: YES, done that and I get the phone number correctly on my page like so: string(14) "12333333333333"

Comment: Appears that something is changing the `$CUphone` variable, as you can see the session in fact exists. But there's no harm in using the `$_SESSION` var directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if the session is already set or not.

```
//That variable should be set an not empty
if (isset($Cphone) && !empty($Cphone)){

    $_SESSION["phone"] = $Cphone ;

    //To check first if the session is set or not
    if(isset($_SESSION['phone'])){

        $CUphone = $_SESSION["phone"];

        echo $CUphone;
    }

}else{

    echo 'session not set';
}
```

in that case, you will either get an error to trace, which comes from the variable or it will work.